# No me da error pero no registra el pedido en la base de datos Jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Sigo con mi intento de acabar con el proyecto de fin de curso. He decidido hacer a través de php crear el carrito y recuperar los datos de la sesión para luego guardarlo en la base de datos. He puesto un echo para ver si realmente recibe los datos y veo que lo imprime, lo pongo debajo del código. Pero después me da un error que incluyo más abajo y no entiendo porqué ya que se supone que los datos los está recibiendo.

Nuevo código

```
    <?php 
     include_once '../../../baseDatos.php'; //para la conexión
     include_once 'carrito.php';//para recuperar el carrito de la sesión
      
      
     if(isset($_GET['btn_confirm'])){
    
    
         if(isset($_COOKIE['UserId']) && isset($_COOKIE['numPedido'])){
    
    
            $idUser = $_COOKIE['UserId'];
            $idPed  = $_COOKIE['numPedido'];
            //Hacemos la conexión con la base de datos 
            $database = "techstore_db";
            $con = crearConexion($database);
    
            //Creo el carrito
            $carrito = new Carrito();
    
            //Llamo a la función pedido($carrito) para que cargue lo que hay en la sesion
            $response = pedido($carrito);
            //valido la respuesta recibida es correcta
            if($response['statuscode'] == 200){         
                header("Location:../../../perfil.php");
    
            }else{
    
                //Muestra un error 
                echo $response['response'];
    
            }
    
            //Cierro la conexión.
            mysqli_close($con); 
       }
    }          
    //llamo a esta función al pulsar el botón tramitar desde main.js mediante la acción pedido línea 27 de este archivo
    function pedido($carrito){
        //Cargar el array que tenemos en la sesión activa
        //Consultar DB para actualizar valores de los productos si han cambiado los precios por ejemplo
        $itemsCarrito = json_decode($carrito->load(), 1);
        $fullItems = []; //Array para todos los productos que hay en el carrito.
        $total = 0; //El total de todo el carrito
        $totalItems = 0; // Total productos agregados al carrito 
    
        //Recorro el array 
        foreach($itemsCarrito as $itemCarrito){
            //Consultar con la base de datos para actualizar datos que hay en la base de datos, por ejemplo un cambio en los precios.
            //Hay que hacer esta consulta cada vez que quiera mostrar el carrito. 
            $httpRequest = file_get_contents('http://localhost/techstore/tienda/api/productos/mostrar.php?get-item=' . $itemCarrito['id']);
            //Decodifico la respuesta y le asigno una variable y le asigno el objeto [item] obtenido. Es un array con valores del item solicitado 
            $itemProducto = json_decode($httpRequest, 1)['item'];
            //añado la cantidad que tiene guardada en la sesión
            $itemProducto['cantidad'] = $itemCarrito['cantidad'];
            //Y el subtotal al multiplicarlo por el precio
            $itemProducto['subtotal'] = $itemProducto['cantidad'] * $itemProducto['precio'];
            //Consigo el total al sumar todos los subtotales
            $total += $itemProducto['subtotal'];
            //sumo todas las cantidades para saber el total Items que hay en el carrito
            $totalItems += $itemProducto['cantidad'];
            //Añado al array fullItems el nuevo item
            array_push($fullItems, $itemProducto);
        }
         
        //Imprimo el array
      
        echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 200, 'items' => $fullItems]); 
    
    }
    
    ?>
```

json recibido

```
{"statuscode":200,"items":[{"id":"25","nombre":"ACER","marca":"Acer","precio":"1300","descripcion":"Nuevo acer","imagen":"juguete07.jpeg","stock":"10","catId":"1","idTrabajador":"4","cantidad":3,"subtotal":3900},{"id":"26","nombre":"Nuevo Producto Porta","marca":"Brother","precio":"1000","descripcion":"Prueba con marca","imagen":"juguete01.jpg","stock":"1000","catId":"1","idTrabajador":"1","cantidad":3,"subtotal":3000}]}
```

error recibido

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\techstore\tienda\api\carrito\tramitar.php on line 31

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\techstore\tienda\api\carrito\tramitar.php on line 42

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes, gran nickname! Pregunta: cuando indicas que no da error, revisaste en los logs de PHP? Si no es así, por favor revisa y añade lo que encuentres en la pregunta, yendo a [edit]

Comment: y también procura solo poner el código relevante. Revisa primero si la conexion a la base de datos es correcta, revisa si el envio del formulario si se hace, revisa si se ejecuta correctamente el post (así no haga nada). una vez identificado el problema puedes poner el código relevante al problema... porque si pones toda tu app, es muy complicado sentarse a revisar cientos de lineas repartidas en varios archivos.

Comment: Observa lo que pasas en Ajax: `data: {idUser:idUser, idPed:idPed, idProd:idProd, cant:cant, prec:prec}`, cuando recojas los valores con `$_POST`. **debes usar las claves que hay a la izquierda**. Por ejemplo, esto es incorrecto: `$cant = $_POST['cantidad'];` porque tú usaste la clave **`cant`** para asociar el valor, no `cantidad`, por tanto, deberías ponerlo así: **`$cant   = $_POST['cant'];`** Verifica que todo coincida en ese aspecto. El código es mejorable en otros puntos, pero empecemos por esto.

Comment: Para una depuración eficaz, que evitará que te desesperes, considera revisar los logs de error, como sugiere @Alfabravo. Si no sabes cómo hacer eso, mientras aprendes, puedes poner estas tres líneas al inicio de tu archivo php: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Cuando ya no haya errores quitas esas líneas. Y en la pregunta agrega todos los mensajes de error o advertencias que veas (como texto) pulsando en [edit]. De este modo podrás ver los errores específicos y si no sabes cómo resolverlos nosotros de ayudaremos.

Comment: @Pipe y al resto. Perdón si puse de más, soy novata :-(. Creí que ayudaría.

Comment: @A. Cedano. Los nombres de los POST, los cambié para probar, porque eran los nombres que tenían los campos que recibía del json, ya los había vuelto a cambiar, porque no me funcionaba.

Comment: @A Cedano, he estado poniendo varios log y he visto que el problema es que no pasa los datos que tengo en el formulario de compras.php a la función js de tramitar.js. Los array se imprimen vacios. Con el número de items que tiene el pedido, pero vacios. He realizado la prueba de introducir en unos input los valores manualmente por ver si el problema estaba en lo que recibo del json, pero tampoco me pasa los datos, y no lo entiendo porque había mirado un video donde lo hacía así.

Comment: Pon las tres líneas que te sugerí más arriba y agrega a la pregunta todos los mensajes de error o advertencias que veas para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Creo que estás confundiendo varios conceptos y sin ver los problemas específicos no podremos ayudarte con rapidez a corregir los varios problemas de tu código.

Comment: Una cosa que me extrañó mucho desde el principio fue ver un `fetch` (de Javascript) dentro de un `form`¿ ? Generalmente `fetch` (o Ajax) se usan para pasar datos entre cliente y servidor, verlo dentro del `form` es sospechoso, o quizá es que no entiendes del todo cómo funciona y te has aventurado en un código lleno de confusiones y malas prácticas. ¿Por qué ese `fetch` dentro del `form`? ¿Qué pretendes hacer con eso?

Comment: @A.Cedano Con el fetch recibo el json y lo muestro en una tabla (formulario), para después poder mandar a través de jquery y ajax los datos a php. El caso es que los datos que recibo si se muestran en la tabla, es decir, que recibe los datos correctamente, pero si me dices que es raro igual para mandarlos no lo debería hacer así?

Comment: Es como si con el `fetch` pidieras los datos al servidor, para mostrarlos en el cliente, para luego mandarlos de nuevo al servidor, donde ya están ... es a eso a lo que no le veo sentido. ¿Por qué no construyes el formulario desde el servidor directamente? Es decir, se suele usar `fetch` para recoger datos nuevos en el cliente, **datos que el servidor no conoce**, no datos que ya están en el servidor. En otros casos, se usa `fetch` para recoger datos parciales, por ejemplo un `ID`, y mandar a buscar los demás datos en el servidor en base a ese `ID`.

Comment: @A. Cedano los datos están guardados en una sesión y los recupero en formato json, para después grabarlos en el servidor. Es un carrito de la compra. He puesto la linea que me has dicho como php en el inicio del body de compras.php que es donde se recupera el carrito, pero no da un error, se ve como se imprime el objeto recibido: 
{info: {…}, items: Array(2)} Con los datos de los productos que recibo del json

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Hablamos de dos servidores distintos, uno donde está el carrito de la compra y otro donde está tu base de datos? ¿O base de datos y carrito de la compra están en el mismo servidor? Es que si están en el mismo servidor el fetch no tiene ningún sentido para este caso, y aunque fueran dos servidores, puedes hacer una petición de un servidor a otro. ¿Qué sentido tiene pasar por el cliente para pedir los datos vía `fetch` cuando los tienes ya en el contexto del servidor?

Comment: @A. Cedano El carrito se guarda en una sesión no está en ningún servidor. Poniendo dicha dirección recupero lo que está guardado en la sesión pero si me salgo de la aplicación el carrito se vacía porque la sesión se destruye y tengo que volver a añadir los productos.

Comment: No, las variables de sesión existen en el servidor. Es cierto que las sesiones tienen un tiempo en el cual expiran y si quieres guardar esa información tienes que hacerla persistir en la base de datos o en otra parte. El asunto es que no tienes claros los conceptos y eso está produciendo un código totalmente extraño y sin sentido en varios aspectos, como ese de pedir desde el cliente algo que ya debería existir en el servidor.